# Remove space between text and <sup>reference</sup> when text is justified

Tags: html, css, layout

In HTML documents, I use  to insert references. The issue is that they look ugly when the text is justified because the reference itself is treated as a word and doesn't stick to the text.

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

Here is what it actually looks like:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
rials<sup class="reference"><a name="origin_ref_1" href="#target_ref_1">†</a></sup> and hardly
```

The reference is a back and forth link between the reference text at the bottom of the page and the reference symbol inserted in the text (for convenience).

How can I make the reference stick to the text and not have extra spaces?

I tried:

```
position:relative;
left:-xxxx em;
```

It succedded in moving the reference at the right place, but didn't change the amount of space between the words, thus increasing the blank after the reference. Also, the amount XXX is tied to the text justification. It is different for every line....

EDIT:

It seems the issue only affects Safari on MAC platforms. But I haven't fully tested it.

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Nice! That's almost it! The inline-block has the right effect, but removes the sup effect. Please, make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in Chrome, Firefox, or IE; the “†” character sticks to the preceding word, with no added spacing in justification. Please show a minimal example that actually demonstrates the problem. You probably have some CSS that causes it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I use safari and firefox on a MAC. So I can't tell for chrome and IE, but you are right: the issue affects safari but not firefox. The solution has already been found by VitorinoFernandes. I am just awaiting his answer to close the matter. There is no added CSS causing the issue, i think, but there is some missing CSS> See my answer.

Comment: Then you should state this in the question itself, because it means that the problem seems to be limited to Safari on Mac (the problem does not exist in the last Safari version available for Windows). Moreover, the question should still contain a complete minimal document (not just a snippet that does not even contain any justification settings), in order to make the question relevant to future visitors.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Probably. However, please note that I didn't know the problem was on safari only until you pointed it out. I have a code snipet on the question. Justification actually depends on the number of words, the size of the words and the length of the line.  So I can't help there. For instance, in my situation there were browser window sizes in which the problem wasn't visible with exactly the same code. Visitors wishing to try the code must add large words to the example to fill their line length. So, following your advices, I have added the information about safari in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is the one suggested by Vitorino Fernandes in a comment that has been removed. I hope he hasn't been victim of an arbitrary removal of his post just as I have recently been from stack exchange team (who shoot first and ask questions later).

Since he seems no longer there, I hereby reproduce his answer:

To solve the issue I have to set the `<sup>` tag as `inline-block`. It is as simple as that. Then everything is displayed correctly. I have already implemented the solution.

Full CSS code includes:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: super; 
font-size: 60%;
```

Comment: This answer will be accepted as THE answer in two days unless Vitorino Fernandes, the one who found the solution, posts an answer of his own.

Answer (score 1):

```css
a{text-decoration:none;}
sup{padding:0px;margin-right:-5px;}
```

```html
rials<sup class="reference"><a name="origin_ref_1" href="#target_ref_1">†</a></sup> and hardly
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply (+1). But I have tried padding and margin variations with no luck. The solution suggested by @VitorinoFernandes in the comments (which have been deleted it seems) is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

In my experiance this is a problem only when there is any white space in the html between the text in the superscript tag and the parent text it supposed to remain in contact with.

Good: `<p>Hello<sup>footnote</sup> Lorem......</p>`

Bad: `<p>Hello <sup>footnote</sup> Lorem......</p>`

Bad: `<p>Hello<sup> footnote</sup> Lorem......</p>`

If there is no whitespace either space, non-breaking space or linefeed, then the browser will treat the parent text and the sup text as a single word, when computing spacing for justification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is no interfering space. The code I use is exactly the code displayed in the question. To solve the issue I need to set it as inline-block as suggested by VitorinoFernandes in his (removed) comment.